# Nexflow dsl2 if else

Tags: nextflow

I have a nextflow (dsl2) script that looks like this:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2


params.test_py = file(params.baseDir, 'test.py')
params.outdir = file(params.baseDir, 'results')


process parse_test {

    input:
        path input_file
        val test_py
        val outdir

    publishDir "$outdir"

    output:
      path '*analyses.tsv', emit: analyses
      path '*variants.tsv', emit: variants, optional:true
      path '*vcf', emit: vcf, optional:true

    script:

      """
      python ${test_py} $input_file
      """
}

process process1 {

    script:

      """
      echo
      """
}

process process2 {

    script:

      """
      echo
      """
}

workflow {

    data = channel.fromPath('./*txt')

    main:

        parsed = parse_test(data, params.test_py, params.outdir)

        if (parsed.vcf) {
                process1()
        } else {
        process2()
        }

}
```

The test.py script always emits an *analyses.tsv file and sometimes a *variant.tsv and a *vcf file. If a vcf file is produced, I want to run process1, if a vcf file is not produced I want to run process2. Currently the pipeline always runs process1. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: What inputs should `process1` and `process2` receive? Presumably you'd want to call `process1( parsed.vcf )`, but how do you intend to run `process2`? What inputs will it take?

Comment: Process1 input is parsed.vcf, parsed.analyses and parsed.variants. Process2 input is parsed.analyses.